# Does Postgres Support Rlike statment in jsonb columns type?

Tags: database, postgresql, rlike

Does PostgreSQL support MySQL 'RLIKE' / Regexp statement in jsonb columns type ?

for example, need a query which pull from the following table all ids which contains the value 'big':

```
| data                                    |  
| "id" :"bigData" , "content" : "aaa...." |  
| "id" : "biggerData, "content" : "bbb..."|  
| "id": "smallData", "content: "ddd......"|  



Select * from myTable where data Rlike ...
```

Is it Applicable ?

Comment: Actually , my question was not clear, my scenario is to  compose a query using RLIKE for jsonb type coulmns..

Answer (score 2):

If the column contains valid json objects you can use [the ->> operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) and simple `LIKE` or `ILIKE` operator:

```
with my_table(data) as (
values
    ('{"id": "bigData" , "content": "aaa...."}'::jsonb),
    ('{"id": "biggerData", "content": "bbb..."}'),
    ('{"id": "smallData", "content": "ddd......"}')
)

select *
from my_table
where data->>'id' like '%big%';

                   data                    
-------------------------------------------
 {"id": "bigData", "content": "aaa...."}
 {"id": "biggerData", "content": "bbb..."}
(2 rows)
```

In more complicated cases you can also use [the regex pattern matching operator ~](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), e.g.:

```
select *
from my_table
where data->>'id' ~ 'big.*Data';
```

Comment: Sorry for misleading , but i missed in my question the jsonb type , i have reformatted my question with that type ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Klin,
I have used the format of :

```
select * from my_table 
where data ->> 'id' ~* 'big';
```

--> This will search for all id`s which its value contains the sub string "big"